# Application Error: The connection to the server was unsuccessful(localhost:12728)

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, mobile

```
Built a app in meteor using following commands:
meteor build /var/meteor --server=http://localhost:3000

then signed the app using following command:
cd /var/android/
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 release-unsigned.apk eCommerce

then,
$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign 4 release-unsigned.apk eCommerce.apk

Got apk file installed it in my mobile phone but it is not connecting to the server

Even i tried to connect via following command:
meteor run android-device --mobile-server=https://localhost:3000
meteor run android-device -p 3000 --mobile-server=https://localhost:3000

I want to locally debug my app but it is unable to connect to my local mongodb. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.......
```